# How to write to the the beginning of file in F#

Tags: file, f#

I need to write a running number - at the beginning of existing files. All I have been able to do so far is to write to the end of each file. Any help please?

Comment: Show us the code you tried.

Comment: maybe just create new file, write this number to it, then copy contents of existing file and delete old and save new file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about (warning! untested code):

```
open System.IO
File.ReadAllText("c:\\old.txt")
    |> fun s -> let r = new StreamReader(s)
                let data = r.ReadToEnd
                r.Close()
                s.Close()
                data

let writeStringToFile d =
    (File.OpenWrite("c:\\new.txt"), d)
    |> fun ((s : FileStream), (d : string)) -> let r = new StreamWriter(s)
                                               r.WriteLine("new data")
                                               r.Write(d)
                                               r.Close()
                                               s.Close()

getStringFromFile()
|> writeStringToFile
```

EDIT:

Much better solution:

```
File.WriteAllText("c:\\new.txt", "new Text" + File.ReadAllText("c:\\old.txt"))
```

Comment: There is probably a better way of doing this

Comment: There is. File.ReadAllText/WriteAllText.

Comment: @Daniel Good call.  New Solution posted

Comment: works great! i used- 
File.WriteAllText("c:\\old.txt", "new Text" + File.ReadAllText("c:\\old.txt")) so the changed would be on the same file and not in a new one. thanks a lot!